# Optimize two simple MySQL queries - column indexes

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, key-value, entity-attribute-value

I am a novice in the MySQL query optimization and need advice on how to optimize the database for two queries - what indexes I should set up and where. Below the database structure and queries.

```
CREATE TABLE `data_node` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` enum('node','place') DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT '',
  `source_id` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `data_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `data_lat` decimal(8,6) NOT NULL,
  `data_lon` decimal(9,6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `data_node_tag` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `node_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `data_key` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `data_value` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

First query:

```
SELECT *
FROM data_node n
LEFT JOIN data_node_tag nt ON nt.node_id = n.id
WHERE n.type = "place"
  AND nt.data_value LIKE "%place%"
GROUP BY n.data_id LIMIT 100
```

Second query:

```
SELECT *
FROM data_node n
LEFT JOIN data_node_tag nt ON nt.node_id = n.id
WHERE n.source_id = 123
  AND n.type = "node"
  AND nt.data_value = "cafe"
  AND (n.data_lat BETWEEN 1.000000 AND 2.000000)
  AND (n.data_lon BETWEEN 3.000000 AND 4.000000)
GROUP BY n.data_id LIMIT 1000
```

I will be grateful for the help.

Comment: Note that both your queries check for values from the LEFT OUTER JOINed table in the WHERE clause, rendering them to both effectively be INNER JOINs

Comment: And they use an aggregator, without actually aggregating anything

Answer (score 0):

Index:

> > data_node_tag.node_id
> >
> > data_node.source_id
> >
> > data_node.type
> >
> > data_node_tag.data_value
> >
> > data_node.lat
> >
> > data_node.lon.

The engine will pick the one to use based on the cardinality.  You could do less, but it depends on what your data looks like.

Second, you should probably index any field used in your where clause.  Any fields that are *unique* should have a unique index.  You can also create composite indexes on multiple fields, but start with index per field.

The DB engine will only use 1 index per table per query (per alias, really, but don't worry about that) so if you have 2 fields you are querying on you can create a composite index on both of those with a `composite index`

Comment: Column `data_id` is not `AUTOINCREMENT`. Unfortunately none of the fields except `id` is not unique. But thanks for the remaining information. I think they can be useful.

Comment: Composite indexes are usually better.

Answer (score 0):

For the first query, you want an index on `data_node(type, id, data_id)` and `data_node_tag(node_id, data_value)`.

For the second query, you want an index on `data_node(source_id, type, data_lat, data_long, id)` and `data_node_tag(id, data_value)` (this is the same as for the first query).

Comment: One index on all columns or separate index for each of columns?

Comment: The indexes are specified with the columns in the order they should be defined.  Each suggested index is one index.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the suggestions for query1:

1. create index on node_id field of data_node_tag table.
2. change type field from enum to varchar(10) in data_node table and create index on it.
3. if possible avoid like with '%place%', at least left part should not variable to use index. So if you can avoid it then create a partial index on it like first 20 to 20 char as per your requirement.

**Note: Most important index is on node_id field as you are joining both tables based on it. So you can get major performance difference by only this index.**

For further optimization of query 1 & 2 it will depend how much data is filtering by different conditions.

Comment: Is partial index in MyISAM engine?

Comment: yes there is no limitation in myisam which prevent to create partial index....first of all just create an index on node_id field of data_node_tag and check performance...further after checking how much data is filtering by different conditions we can finalize that on which field index should be create...

Answer (score 0):

Use foreign key for **data_node_tag** table for the **id** field. 
Since you have duplicate **id** field. You can use a foreign key to overcome the duplication of data.

`CREATE TABLE data_node_tag (
  id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  node_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  data_key varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  data_value varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES data_node(id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`

Comment: I have not InnoDB, because MyISAM is better for my purpose (frequent reading, a rare modification). And in MyISAM engine there is no foreign keys. But thanks for try! :)

Comment: Was not aware about that...:)

Comment: Your query works (no errors will be displayed), but the foreign key will be ignored. Instead, it will be created only index for this column.

Comment: myisam does not support foreign keys...even foreign key in innodb db also  just provide performance as if you create index on node_id field without foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

(These comments are more of a warning than an answer.)

For `data_node_tag`, get rid of `id`; change to `PRIMARY KEY(node_id, data_key)`.  Even so, you will eventually discover why EAV schema sucks.

You will also discover why lat/lng is difficult to optimize.

Use InnoDB, not MyISAM.

`LIKE "%place%"` cannot be optimized (although `LIKE "place%"` *can* use an index). Consider `FULLTEXT`.